# Can a custom Ruby function defined in one Puppet module be called from a .pp file in another module?

Tags: ruby, puppet

I have a custom function that I need to call (server-side) from at least two different puppet modules. The calls are to be made in Puppet DSL defined types, not Ruby-based custom types and providers.

I know that if I put the definition in a .rb file in the "lib\puppet\parser\functions" directory it is accessible in that module. Can that function be called from other modules, perhaps with some module qualifier before it? Or do I need to use some other approach? The function accepts two string arguments and returns a hash.

The little that I know about custom functions is found here:

https://docs.puppetlabs.com/guides/custom_functions.html

https://docs.puppetlabs.com/guides/plugins_in_modules.html

The following blog post seems to suggest that all functions from all modules are accessible from any module, but I may be misunderstanding it:

http://www.masterzen.fr/2011/10/29/puppet-extension-points-part-1/

Comment: as long as `pluginsync` is enabled, your function should be available to any other manifest.

Comment: Thank you. If you put this as the answer and include a link to a Puppet labs doc that clarifies this, I will accept it as the answer.

Comment: @ptierno `pluginsync` is relevant for the agent only. It is unrelated to parser functions. It *will* sync them to the agent, but manifests can be compiled regardless of that, even when `pluginsync` is disabled (don't do that, though).

Comment: @FelixFrank Thanks for that. I am considering the master as an agent node also i this case. https://docs.puppetlabs.com/guides/plugins_in_modules.html pretty much states that pluginsync should add the custom function to the proper `$libdir` on the master. Probably should have been more specific.

Comment: @ptierno oh wow you're right. That document **does** imply that your answer has merit. I'm quite certain it's outdated, though. I will do some archaeology and report back.

Comment: Yes, turns out it's from early 2010, from before Puppet version 2.6.0. I will try and have it removed, it's incorrect and misleading.

Comment: @FelixFrank  Thanks for that information. I have definitely taken note of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have `pluginsync` enabled, puppet will make available all of your custom `facts`, `types`, `functions`, etc.

In `puppet.conf` set `pluginsync=true`

#### Reference

[Plugins in modules](https://docs.puppetlabs.com/guides/plugins_in_modules.html)

Answer (score 3):

Plugins in modules are always available to the compiler, in any manifest, encompassing all modules. This is true for both types and parser functions.

For example, the `stdlib` module includes the `file_line` type, which is expressly there for use outside of the module.

Comment: Thank you for expanding the answer to include types.